# Cloudwatch event is not triggering the Lambda Function which created through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Please find my code which i tried to create a lambda function and event rules using the cloudformation, the cloudformation was deployed successfully and everything looks good but at the schedule time my event rule is not triggering or invoking the lambda function, i have checked the permissions also everything is fine but doesn't work.

Request you to please help here.

```yaml
Parameters:
  CRONScheduler:
    Description: 'Define the CRON Schedule for the event to trigger'
    Type: String
    Default: cron(* * * * * *)

Resources:
  EventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: 'ScheduledRule'
      ScheduleExpression: !Ref CRONScheduler
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        -
          Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - "LambdaFunction"
              - "Arn"
          Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
          Input: '{"Account_id ": "369885648310"}'

  PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaFunction
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "EventRule"
          - "Arn"

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: "My Lambda Function"
      FunctionName: "MyLambdaFunccc"
      Role: arn:aws:iam::369885648310:role/service-role/myfunction-role-cjkkxygt
      Runtime: python3.8
      #Code:
      #  ZipFile: |
      #      import boto3
      #      def lambda_handler(event,context):
      #        client = boto3.client('ec2')
      #        response = client.describe_instances(InstanceIds = ['i-03de56c4f3969694a'])
      #        for instance in response['Reservations']:
      #          for depth in instance['Instances']:
      #            print('the machine details are {} , {} ,{}'.format(depth['ImageId'],depth['InstanceType'],depth['Monitoring']))

      #Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Code:
        S3Bucket: cftfiles
        S3Key: InstanceStateChange.zip
      Handler: InstanceStateChange.lambda_handler
```

Lambda Permisions:

```yaml
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "MYCFTT-PermissionForEventsToInvokeLambda-JD1QWW6MYAKG",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:369885648310:function:MyLambdaFunccc",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:369885648310:rule/MYCFTT-EventRule-5VIMAR0OVQXD"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your cron expression?

Comment: Look in the rule in the Cloud Watch console and see when it thinks the event is due to be triggered and what lambda is has trying to invoke.

Comment: Have you check the Cloudwatchs logs for the specific lambda to confirm that is not running at all?